# CSS: How to target ::slotted siblings in Shadow DOM root?

Tags: css, web-component, shadow-dom, native-web-component

I know that the spec currently only allows compound selectors for ::slotted, i.e. `::slotted(my-first + my-second)` is not allowed, but should something like this be working?

```
::slotted(x-first) + ::slotted(x-second) { /* css */ }
```

Is there any way to target slotted siblings (other than with global css)? And if not, where would I file such a request? Thanks.

Comment: how this would be different of ::slotted(x-first + x-second)?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Sure you can select `siblings` of `slots / slotted`.

The thing you can **not** do is select a element which has been slotted and is **not a top-level node**.

**Select siblings:**

`slot[name=<slotname>] ~ <selector>`

**Select slotted top-level node**

`::slotted(<compound-selector>)`

A [compound-selector](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#typedef-compound-selector) contains a tag/class/id/name etc. but **must not** have any [combinators](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp). Like `<space>` for example.

`.myClass` OK

`<anyTag>[<anyAttribute>[=<anyValue>]]` OK

`.<myClass> > .<anotherClass>` NO

**Examples**

```js
var element = document.querySelector('.templateMe');
var shadow = element.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
var template = document.querySelector('.myTemplate');
shadow.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
```

```html
<template class="myTemplate">
  <style type="text/css">
    ::slotted([slot=slot1]) { /* slot1 every slotted element - YES */
      color: red;
    }
    
    slot[name=slot1] { /* slot1 itself - YES */
      text-decoration: underline;
    }
    
    slot[name=slot1] + .siblingA { /* slot1 siblingA (direct sibling) - YES */
      color: green;
    }
    
    slot[name=slot1]  ~ .siblingB { /* slot1 siblingB (any sibling) - YES */
      color: orange;
    }
    
    slot[name=slot2]::slotted(.selectMeA) { /* slot2 TOP-LEVEL CHILD (slotted) - YES */
      color: purple;
    }
    
    slot[name=slot2]::slotted(.selectMeB) { /* slot2 NOT TOP-LEVEL CHILD - NO */
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    slot[name=slot2]::slotted(.selectMeC[name=myName]) { /* slot2 TOP-LEVEL CHILD (slotted) - YES */
      color: khaki;
    }
    
    slot[name=slot2] + .siblingC { /* slot2 sibling - YES */
      color: blue;
    }
    
  </style>
  <div>
    <slot name="slot1"></slot>
    <div class="siblingA">Sibling A of Slot 1</div>
    <div class="siblingB">Sibling B of Slot 1</div>
  </div>
  <hr/>
  <div>
    <slot name="slot2"></slot>
    <div class="siblingC">Sibling C of Slot 2</div>
  </div>
</template>

<div class='templateMe'>
  <span slot="slot1">Im in Solt 1</span>
  <span slot="slot2" class="selectMeA">
    Im in Solt 2, im selectable.
    <div class='selectMeB'>
      NOT selectable (because no top level node of slotted)!
    </div>
  </span>
  <span slot="slot2" class="selectMeC" name="myName">Im in Solt 2 too and selectable!</span>
</div>
```

More [here](https://javascript.info/shadow-dom-style#styling-slotted-content).

> slotted elements (coming from light DOM), ::slotted(selector) allows to select slotted elements themselves, but not their children.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. In your example, what I was looking for would have been: `slot[name=slot2]::slotted(.selectMeA + .selectMeC)`, which, if I understand you correctly, is not possible, although both are top level children.

Comment: thats correct since you are using `+` which is a combinator

Comment: I've tried `::slotted(.selectMeA) + ::slotted(.selectMeC)` but this is not wirking aswell. `::slotted` seems to be the end of the line.

Comment: Anyone know if this is how this was done for a reason, or if combinators might work in the future but don't yet? I want them 

Answer (score 7):

DOM that is placed into a slot is supposed to be controlled by the CSS that owns that DOM and not by the Custom Element.

The Web Component it allowed very minor CSS control over the DOM that is placed into your Slot. Pretty much just the top level elements (And things that are auto inherited by child nodes.)

This was a conscious decision and will probably never change.

Comment: Thanks, I have also read that the decision to disallow complex selectors with ::slotted had to do with performance when targeting *descendents*. Therefore I had hoped that there was a way to target slotted *siblings*, since those *are* top level elements.