# Combinators for multiple ::slotted elements

Tags: css, web-component, shadow-dom, custom-element

I am interested if there's a way to achieve something like the following:

```
::slotted(input[type="checkbox"]:disabled) ~ ::slotted(label) {
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

By testing it on some of the examples, it does not work.
[Specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-scoping/#slotted-pseudo) does not describe if this should be possible or not. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::slotted) does not cover this case as well.

I do not want to enclose neither `input` nor `label` inside the `shadow-dom` as I do not want to handle and/or duplicate the native behavior of those elements.

P.S. I know that I can do that with javascript (for example, by adding class to slotted `label`), but I'm looking for a plain css solution.

Full example:

```html
<script>
  customElements.define('my-element', class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super();
      const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
        shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
            <style>
              ::slotted(input:disabled) ~ ::slotted(label) {
                color: red;
              }
              ::slotted(input:disabled) + ::slotted(label) {
                color: red;
              }
            </style>
            <slot name="inputel"></slot>
            <slot name="inputlabel"></slot>`;
      }
  });
</script>
<my-element>
  <input disabled id="input1" type="text" slot="inputel"/>
  <label for="input1" slot="inputlabel">label</label>
</my-element>
```

Comment: Can you add the full HTML, preferably a working SO snippet. Where are ``input`` and ``label``?

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman added.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS: How to target ::slotted siblings in Shadow DOM root?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49678342/css-how-to-target-slotted-siblings-in-shadow-dom-root)

Comment: @lamplightdev not really, but it definitely has some interesting insights, thanks for linking it!

Answer (score 2):

The full detailed explanation is at: [::slotted CSS selector for nested children in shadowDOM slot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61626493/slotted-css-selector-for-nested-children-in-shadowdom-slot/61631668#61631668)

---

```
<my-element>
  <input disabled id="input1" type="text" slot="inputel"/>
  <label for="input1" slot="inputlabel">label</label>
</my-element>
```

> ShadowDOM SLOTs *turn off* the light

The `input` and `label` are in ***lightDOM***,
and remain there **invisible** when **reflected** (not moved!) to ***shadowDOM*** `SLOTs`

So you have to style them in ***lightDOM***:

```
    <style>
      /* style lightDOM!! */
      my-element input:disabled ~ label {
        color: red;
      }
    </style>
```

```html
<template id="MY-ELEMENT">
  <style>
    ::slotted(input:disabled){
      border:1px dashed red;
    }
  </style>
INPUT <slot name="inputElement"></slot> <slot name="inputLabel"></slot>
</template>
<script>
  customElements.define('my-element', class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super().attachShadow({mode: 'open'})
             .append(document.getElementById(this.nodeName).content.cloneNode(true));
      }
  });
</script>
<style>
  /* style lightDOM!! */
  my-element input:disabled ~ label {
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
</style>
<my-element>
  <input disabled id="inp1" placeholder="This is disabled" type="text" slot="inputElement"/>
  <label for="inp1" slot="inputLabel">input label 1</label>
</my-element>
<br>
<my-element>
  <input id="inp2" placeholder="Not disabled" type="text" slot="inputElement"/>
  <label for="inp2" slot="inputLabel">input label 2</label>
</my-element>
```

This use case is a bit contrived, there is nothing gained with `my-element`, user still has to declare `input` and `label`

Maybe create a `<input-element  type="text"  label="A Label">` to create above HTML, you then have the disabled CSS in its shadowDOM (no need for SLOTs)

or  (pseudo code)

```
<template id="INPUT-ELEMENT">
  <style>
    input:disabled~label{
      color:red;
    }
  </style>
  <input id="i"/>
  <label for="i"><slot name="label"></slot></label>
</template>

...
connectedCallback(){
  let inp=this.shadowRoot.querySelector("input");
  inp.type = this.getAttribute("type");
  inp.toggleAttribute( "disabled" , this.hasAttribute("disabled"));
}


<input-element type="text" disabled>
  <span slot="label"><b>Fancy Label<b></slot>
</input-element>
```

if you want to give the user more control

---

**::slotted** came got into WebComponents V1 spec after its predecessor caused performance issues in V0
Thus it only takes simple selectors as parameter, and can only style first-level elements in the slot

So in above example `::slotted` can style the `<span slot="label">`, but not the `<b>` inside.

**Note:** `SLOTs` are LIVE connections, you can re-apply CSS at any time, and content changes are immediately **reflected** to shadowDOM:

`document.querySelector("input-element > b").innerHTML="Better Label!";`

---

More SLOT related answers can be found with StackOverflow Search: [Custom Elements SLOTs](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22Custom-Elements-SLOTs%22&so=uri&tab=newest)

Comment: thank you for your time, but this is exactly what I try to avoid. I do not see any sense in overriding native elements and/or enclosing native elements inside shadow dom. Styling them on the client-side is an option, but I do not have control over that as this component is exported in a library and the user is supposed to only pass input and label elements, the library should handle the styling.

Comment: That 'no control' then includes the placement of input and label tags, your user can place the label before the input.. and then use a ``float:right`` to **display** it after the input..